# Web performance analyzer that works offline / locally (alternate to YSlow)

Tags: web-development, profiling

I am looking for an alternate for [YSlow](http://yslow.org).

**We like it since it has the following great features:**

- It is open source
- We can use it locally to test the script, before we put the app live.
- It can be integrated with Firefox, since it is a browser that we use for our development.
- It considers a great range of options for performance improvements.
- It was developed by a reputed team of developers from Yahoo.

**Why we are looking for an alternate**:

- Firefox (and Chrome) no longer support its adds on, it is not useable on either of them.
- This project is abandoned and it is no longer being updated.

**Update**: *Page Insights* from google used to work offline, but now it was discontinued and now google suggest its online version https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/'>here.

Comment: No longer being updated does not necessarily mean, it's abandoned. Do you have some official statement about the lack of updates?

Comment: @Marcel I do not have an statement from the author saying "I do not want to maintain this software any longer for this reason", but I say that, since the most recent release is not compatible with any of the tools they claim to be.